# Change row height of the first row of a table and the paragraph line spacing

Tags: excel, vba, macos, ms-word

I copied a set of tables from Excel into Word and formatted each one.

```vb
For t = 1 To 6
    With appWD.Selection.Tables(t)
        .TopPadding = 0
        .BottomPadding = 0
        .LeftPadding = 0.11
        .RightPadding = 0
        .Spacing = 0
        .AllowPageBreaks = True
        .AllowAutoFit = True
        .Rows.SetHeight RowHeight:=12, HeightRule:=2
    End With
Next t
```

To accommodate a larger font, I need to change the row height of the first row and also to change the paragraph line spacing.

This piece of code fails to do this.

```vb
For t = 1 To 6
    With appWD.Selection.Tables(t).Rows(1)
        .SetHeight RowHeight:=18
        .ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = 15
    End With
Next t
```

I'm running Excel/Word 2016 on a Mac.

Comment: Look at the argument differences in your .SetHeight lines...

Comment: Sorry, not sure I follow. Are you saying I need to add "Rows." to the beginning of the SetHeight line in the 2nd routine? If so, does this apply to the ParagraphFormat line too? Thanks.

Comment: .Rows is not an argument of .SetHeight

Comment: Still no wiser - the first routine works with .Rows.SetHeight. The second doesn't. Either way, if anyone can tell me how to achieve what I need, I would be very, very grateful! Thanks again.

Comment: Having manually changed the row height in the output, I'm not sure I need to worry about the paragraph format so the question simplifies to 'how do I change the row height of the first row in a table?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using appWD.Selection is poor practice. You have an open document you want to work on, so reference that directly. For example:

```
With wdDoc
  For t = 1 To 6
    With .Tables(t)
      .TopPadding = 0
      .BottomPadding = 0
      .LeftPadding = 0.11
      .RightPadding = 0
      .Spacing = 0
      .AllowPageBreaks = True
      .AllowAutoFit = True
      .Rows.SetHeight RowHeight:=12, HeightRule:=2
      .Rows(1).SetHeight RowHeight:=18, HeightRule:=1
      .Rows(1).Range.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = 15
    End With
  Next t
End With
```

Note the the inclusion of the appropriate HeightRule argument for the Row 1 SetHeight method. Note also that all the processing is done in a single loop, rather than the two loops your code used.

Comment: Thank you so much - this works fine and is so simple! Despite extensive 'old school' programming some 30 years ago, self-teaching vba clearly has many pitfalls. It's great to have access to experts like you.

Comment: Interestingly, it turns out that the .ParagraphFormat isn't working, with the value remaining stubbornly the same as the rest of the table. As I said in an earlier comment, this isn't important in this instance but I'm hopeful of finding the solution at some point.

Comment: ParagraphFormat code revised.

Comment: Yep - that fixed it thanks!